# Backbone view not updating properly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to display a list, and once an item in the list is clicked on, I want the list to be hidden, and to retrieve and show the item's details.

The mouse click fires, the details are retrieved from the REST web service, and the item list is hidden.  The problem is that the item details don't appear until I refresh the page.  I can't quite see what I'm doing wrong.

Here's an example of my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Backbone Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.7.1-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div>VIN Search List:</div>
<div id="item-list" />
<div id="item-details" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{
    var Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: "rest/search",
        defaults: {
            "uid": ""
        }
    });    

    var Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Item,
        url: "rest/search/", 
    });

    var ItemDetail = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: "rest/search/details",
        defaults: {
            "uid": "",
            "details": ""
        },

        url : function() {
            return this.id ? this.urlRoot + '/' + this.id : this.urlRoot;
        } 
    });    

    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        tagName: "ol",

        initialize: function() 
        {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
        },

        render: function() 
        {
            _.each(this.model.models, function(uid) {
                $(this.el).append( new ItemView({model:uid}).render().el );
            }, this);  
            return this;
        },

        close: function() 
        {
            $(this.el).unbind();
            $(this.el).remove();
        },
    });

    var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        tagName: "li",

        template: _.template("<%= uid %>"),

        events: { "click": "showDetails" },

        initialize: function() 
        {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
            this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
        },

        render: function(eventName) 
        {
            $(this.el).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
            return this;
        },

        close: function() 
        {
            $(this.el).unbind();
            $(this.el).remove();
        },

        showDetails: function() 
        {
            app.navigate("details/" + this.model.get("uid"), {trigger: true});
            return false;
        },
    });

    var DetailsView = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        tagName: "ul",

        template: _.template("<li><%= uid %></li><li><%= details %></li>"),

        initialize: function() 
        {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
            this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
        },

        render: function(eventName) 
        {
            $(this.el).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
            return this;
        },

        close: function() 
        {
            $(this.el).unbind();
            $(this.el).remove();
        },
    });

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes:
        {
            "": "list",
            "details/:uid": "Details"
        },

        list: function() 
        {
            var self = this;
            this.itemList = new Items();
            this.itemList.fetch(
            {
                success: function() 
                {
                    self.listView = new ListView({model: self.itemList});
                    $('#item-list').html( self.listView.render().el );
                }
            });
        },

        Details: function(uid) 
        {
            if (this.lListView) this.listView.close();

            var self = this;
            this.details = new ItemDetail({id: uid});
            this.details.fetch(
            {
                success: function() 
                {
                    self.detailsView = new DetailsView({model: self.details});
                    $('#item-details').html( self.detailsView.render().el );
                }
            });
        },

    });

    // Start up
    var app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
</script>
```

Comment: When the Details route is fired, the DetailsView isn't rendered until the page is refreshed.

Comment: Yep, success gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change the Details route to modify #item-list instead of #item-details, everything behaves correctly.

<s>I'm guessing that since #item-list was the element originally modified in the default route, that I can't modify elements located outside it's heirarchy?  I'd really like to understand this behavior.</s>

Blargh.  It looks like I just have to manually toggle the display of the #item-details element to force the element to be rendered.  I'm still not sure why the default route behaves differently, but it's not a huge issue.

```
        this.details.fetch(
        {
            success: function() 
            {
                self.detailsView = new DetailsView({model: self.details});
                $('#item-details').html( self.detailsView.render().el );
                $('#item-details').css( "display", "block" ); // FORCE DISPLAY
            }
        });
```